# Can German Covpass app store 4th covid vaccine dose information?

Tags: germany, covid-19, mobile-apps

I already have my two primary vaccine doses and one booster dose and all are stored in the Covpass app and can be scanned as a QR code etc.

It so happens that in several foreign nations the last vaccination dose is considered valid if within the previous 8 months. Eg Switzerland

I was considering getting a 2nd booster dose at some point i.e. a 4th total dose.

Was wondering if the German Covpass app has the ability to import this 4th certificate? Anyone know?

At this point it's only a select group of vulnerable people that are reccomended the 4th dose I believe.

PS. Right now my latest (booster) dose shows up as 3/3 on the Covpass app. I wonder if it has been modified to include 4 doses now.

PS. Also what about the Swiss app etc. Do they allow a 4th dose to be stored?

Comment: I cannot guarantee that there is no funny business in the Covpass app but in principe it doesn't need to be modified to support additional doses, "3/3" is something that is encoded in the certificate and supported from the beginning. So you can easily generate and store certificates with sequence numbers like "3/1" and "4/4".

Comment: The EU covid passes used to show 2/2. Mine still does as well as the 3/3 booster.

Comment: Don't worry. I think that quite a few people in Germany have already received a 4th dose and the app supports that. Health workers (more or less in general) and people with specific diseases are recommended to get a 4th dose, but you can usually also get one voluntarily. I asked for and got a 4th dose already in February just because I was concerned that the 3rd dose should 'expire' and not be recognized by other countries for travel purposes during the next months.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the CovPass app shows the 2nd booster dose as 4/4.

- based on a certificate issued on the 2022-04-05

The CovPass-Check app simply says that it is valid.

All of the applications use the same base source code, so the swiss (and others) should work in the same way as far as the reading and writing of the qr-code is concerned.

The image below shows a portion of the pdf created by the CovPass app:

[image]